# He was never anything but decent toward me

Tags: sentence-meaning

I saw it in the Game of Throne and I felt kind of confused about this sentence.

> He was never anything but decent toward me.

Is positive or negative?

Comment: It's not high praise, but it's generally positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s a positive statement affirming the person was treated well, or with respect.